# Java getter method not displaying the changed value

Tags: java

The employee have to complete set of predefined certificates which is given in the certificates array in findRating function. If the certificate done by the employee does not match the predefined certificates the rating will not change. Each match will increase the rating by one.

This question demands to change the rating of the employee according to the certificated the employee has done. Code i have written is changing the value but when called by the getter method getRating() it is showing 0. 
this is the main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
public static void main (String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the employee id:");
     String id = sc.next();
     System.out.println("Enter the salary:");
     double sal = sc.nextDouble();
     System.out.println("Enter the no of certification complete:");
    int numCer = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the certification names:");
    String [] certi = new String[numCer];

    for(int i = 0;i<numCer;i++){
        certi[i] = sc.next();
    }

    Employee emp = new Employee(id,sal,certi);
    System.out.println("Your rating is "+emp.getRating());
    //emp.findRating();
    System.out.println("Increment amount is "+emp.calculateIncrement());
    System.out.println("Current Salary "+emp.getSalary());
}
}
```

this is the employee class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
 public class Employee{
     private String employeeId;
     private double salary;
     private String [] certification;
     private int rating;

     public Employee(String empid, double sal, String[] certi){
         employeeId = empid;
        salary = sal;
        certification = Arrays.copyOf(certi,certi.length);
        this.rating = 0;

    }



    public void findRating(){
        String allCerti [] = {"JAVA","ORACLE","GCUX","CCNA","AWS"};
        int len = this.certification.length;
        // int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<len;i++){
            String target = this.certification[i];
            for(String s: allCerti){
                if(s.equals(target)){
                    this.rating++;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public double calculateIncrement(){
        switch(this.rating){
        case 1: return (this.salary * 2)/100;
        case 2: return (this.salary * 3.5)/100;
        case 3: return (this.salary * 5)/100;
        case 4: return (this.salary * 7.5)/100;
        case 5: return (this.salary * 10)/100;
        default: return 0; 
    }
    }

    public int getRating(){
       return rating;
    }

    public double getSalary(){
     double inc = calculateIncrement();
     return (salary + inc);
   }
   }
```

Comment: You not called method findRating method, which is actually changes the rating field.

Comment: This is because you have set the value of this.rating = 0 in your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine just call `findRating()` method for getRating()  and also in calculateIncrenment , :

```
 public int getRating(){
    findRating();
    return rating;
}



   public double calculateIncrement(){
    switch(getRating()){    // call method getRating instead directrly 
                                //accessing it 
    case 1: return (this.salary * 2)/100;
    case 2: return (this.salary * 3.5)/100;
    case 3: return (this.salary * 5)/100;
    case 4: return (this.salary * 7.5)/100;
    case 5: return (this.salary * 10)/100;
    default: return 0; 
}
}
```

and

```
   public void findRating(){
               this.rating =0 ; // set to zero before calculating rating each time
```

**Sample Run**

```
Enter the employee id:
12
Enter the salary:
20000
Enter the no of certification complete:
4
Enter the certification names:
JAVA
PYTHON
ORACLE
SQL
Your rating is 2
Increment amount is 1500.0
Current Salary 21500.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `findRating()` method to calculate the rating, you have not calculated the rating yet.

What you can do is setRating as `0` in. the beginning of `findRating()` and then calculate the rating and to encapsulate the code, call the findRating() from inside getRating() and not outside as below. :

```
    public void findRating(){
        this.rating = 0 ;
        String allCerti [] = {"JAVA","ORACLE","GCUX","CCNA","AWS"};
        int len = this.certification.length;
        // int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<len;i++){
            String target = this.certification[i];
            for(String s: allCerti){
                if(s.equals(target)){
                    this.rating++;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

and

```
public int getRating(){
        findRating();
        return rating;
    }
```